# Answering ___もいいですか with すみません, ___ ですから

Tags: particle-から, permission

I don't think I fully understand the answer in this conversation:

> Q: ここにくるまおとめてもいいですか.

> A: すみません, みせのまえですから.

It seems to me that the answer states that it is OK to park in front of the store. But what is the role of すみません and から? If we label すみません as "I am sorry" and から as "because", then "I am sorry, because you can park in front of the store" doesn't make sense. Does すみません mean something like "I am sorry, but no" in this sentence?

I am also curious why the answer simply uses みせのまえです. Shouldn't it be something like みせのまえにいいです?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Q: ここにくるまをとめてもいいですか. Is it ok to park the car here?

> A: すみません, みせのまえですから. No, sorry. Not in front of the store.

すみません is used as a way to politely refuse permission in Japanese. Furthermore, `REASON + から` is used to explain why. In your example, the から is being used to explain the reason why permission is being denied. In this case, it's because parking in front of the store is not allowed.

Comment: Ah, so the みせのまえですから part means "because [the place where you want to park] is in the front of the store"?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.